# Conjugate gradient method's convergence steps

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I met a question that asks me to show that if the $A$ of $Ax = b$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and all its eigenvalues are 1, 2, or 8. Then the conjugate gradient method converges in 3 or fewer steps.

I don't know where to start, did I missed some important knowledge between its convergence and $A$'s eigenvalues?

Comment: There is a relation between convergence of conjugate gradients (and Krylov methods in general) and a degree of the minimal polynomial of a matrix. That might be the important knowledge you speak of since understanding this relation will give you your answer.

Comment: @Korf I searched many times on the Internet, but can't find the relation between CG and A's minimal polynomial....

Comment: @Korf, So do you mean, it's because the error e_k will <=2c^k * e_0 after k steps where the c is sqrt (maximum eigenvalue/minimum eigenvalue) -1/ sqrt (maximum eigenvalue/minimum eigenvalue) +1? so even for the worse case (has eigenvalue 8 and 1), 2c^k will begin to be <=1 within 3 steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error $e_k:=x-x_k$ at step $k$ of CG [satisfies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#Convergence_theorem)
$$\tag{1}
\|e_k\|_A=\min_{p\in\Pi_k \\ p(0)=1}\|p(A)e_0\|_A,
$$
where $\Pi_k$ is the set of polynomials of degree at most $k$. If $A$ has only $k$ distinct eigenvalues, you can take $p$ in (1) to be the minimal polynomial of $A$. Since $p(A)=0$ you get that $e_k=0$.